# VSIX package gets installed by Wix but not uninstalled

Tags: wix, vsix

I created a Wix installer that installs a VSIX using the VsixPackage extension. The VSIX gets installed properly however two things are bugging me:

- The user has the possibility to uninstall the VSIX through the tools / Extensions menu in VS.
- When I uninstall the MSI, the VSIX doesn't get uninstalled.

I did set the Permanent attribute of the VsixPackage to no. Here is the markup:

```
                            <Component Id="VSIXVS11"
                                   Guid="2C85F474-3E44-4A38-AC2D-0A6F6B1049DA">
                            <VSExtension:VsixPackage File="MvvmLight.VS2012.vsix"
                                                        PackageId="MVVM Light..e8b05c55-a169-42aa-a116-064ef2205f80"
                                                        Target="professional" 
                                                        TargetVersion="11.0" 
                                                        Vital="yes" 
                                                        Permanent="no"/>

                            <File Id="MvvmLight.VS2012.vsix"
                                  Name="MvvmLight.VS2012.vsix"
                                  DiskId="1"
                                  Source="..\..\InstallItems\VSIX\Release\MvvmLight.VS2012.vsix" />
                        </Component>
```

Any idea what causes the VSIX to not get uninstalled?

Note: The VSIX's "This VSIX is installed by Windows Installer" flag is not set. If I try to set it, I get an error when running the MSI.

Comment: I have the same problem. It worked first for both sample project and my primary project but now it doesn't work for both projects for unknown reason. My version of WIX toolset is 3.6

Comment: I'm having the same issues, even with WiX 3.8. There is no difference if `Permanent` is set to `yes` or `no`

Answer (score 1):

You have a space in the package ID.
Escape the package ID like so:

```
<VSExtension:VsixPackage File="MvvmLight.VS2012.vsix"
     PackageId="&quot;MVVM Light..e8b05c55-a169-42aa-a116-064ef2205f80&quot;"
     Target="professional" 
     TargetVersion="11.0" 
     Vital="yes" 
     Permanent="no"/>
```

Comment: This issue is fixed in recent builds of WiX v3.9.